# Admob ads are showing in Emulator but no status in Admob account

Tags: android, admob

The application is configured with Admob code and the app is displaying the ads in the Emulator but no green status in the Admob account, the status is still in red color. It has been one day configured with Admob code in the app but there is no status change. In the site url, the package name is given in this format, market://details?id=package name

Answer (score 4):

The App needs to be released to the market, and admob will recognise when
a phone has received an Ad, and change status to green.
Ads in emulator will not activate the status as it is a test device,
which has probably been listed in the xml file.
You are not supposed to click on ads in your own App's, which is why the test device
and / or your own phone should be listed in the xml file so that
Admob ignors ads to these devices.